# How to push a box inside a Google Map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to put a box inside a Google Map.
I have a map, a box under it, but i don't know how can i push the box to stay inside the map.

Here i have made a simple example:

http://jsbin.com/avAmEpAZ/1/edit

You can watch it full-screen to understand better: http://jsbin.com/avAmEpAZ/1

Do you know how this can be obtained?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can use an overlay of map...research in maps API docs. Alternatively wrap map in dimensioned element with position relative, place box inside that element as sibling of map, position box absolute and adjust z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come out with this solution:

var input = (document.getElementById('--BOX_ID--'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

You can check it here:

http://jsbin.com/avAmEpAZ/3/edit
http://jsbin.com/avAmEpAZ/3

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to use pure CSS.
Make sure the z-index is greater than the google map z-index.

```
#sizer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 340px;
    top: 180px;
    margin-left:-170px;
    left:50%;
}
```